# PostgreSQL: GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

Tags: postgresql

Всем привет.

Есть такой запрос,

```
SELECT
        global_user_id
        , os_family_1
    FROM (
        SELECT
            MD5(CONCAT(CASE WHEN bums.global_user_id::VARCHAR IS NULL THEN 'NULL'::VARCHAR ELSE bums.global_user_id::VARCHAR END)) AS global_user_id
            , dos.os_family_1 AS os_family_1
            , MAX(fpv.page_view_date) AS max_page_view_date
            , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY bums.global_user_id ORDER BY fpv.page_view_date DESC) AS rn
        FROM "database"."data_warehouse__prod"."fact_page_views" AS fpv
        LEFT JOIN "database"."data_warehouse__prod"."dim_browser" AS dib ON dib.browser_key = fpv.browser_key
        LEFT JOIN "database"."data_warehouse__prod"."dim_os" AS dos ON dos.os_key = fpv.os_key
        LEFT JOIN "database"."data_warehouse__prod"."dim_page" AS dip ON dip.page_key = fpv.page_key
        LEFT JOIN "database"."data_warehouse__prod"."dim_snowplow_user" AS dsu ON dsu.snowplow_user_key = fpv.snowplow_user_key
        LEFT JOIN "database"."data_warehouse__prod"."outrigger_dim_site" AS ods ON ods.site_name = dip.page_app_id
        LEFT JOIN "database"."data_warehouse__prod"."bridge_user_model_snowplow" AS bums ON dsu.snowplow_user_key = bums.snowplow_user_key
        WHERE
            fpv.page_view_date::DATE >= (('2022-02-02'::DATE + -8 * INTERVAL '1 week'))
            AND fpv.page_view_date::DATE < (('2022-02-02'::DATE + 0 * INTERVAL '1 day'))
            AND (dib.is_a_bot) = 'This Is Not A Bot'
            AND (dib.is_internal_traffic) = 'This Is Not Internal Traffic'
            AND (ods.site_id IS NOT NULL)
        group by 1,2
        ) AS os_family_1
    WHERE rn = 1
```

но почему-то получаю ошибку.

```
column "fpv.page_view_date" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
LINE 18: ...) OVER (PARTITION BY bums.global_user_id ORDER BY fpv.page_v...
```

Сам не могу разобраться.

Comment: А перевести сообщение об ошибке не пробовали? очень помогает... речь идёт о поле, которое используется для сортировки в оконной функции - а она выполняется после группировки, когда поля исходных таблиц, не включённых в выражение группировки, уже недоступны.

Comment: Та переводить-то пробовал. Но даже после Вашего комментария я не понял (

Comment: Дело в том, что когда я включил эту колонку в группировку (group by 1,2,3), то получил уже другую ошибку: aggregate functions are not allowed in GROUP BY , MAX(fpv.page_view_date) AS max_page_view_date

Comment: Правильно. Следует посчитать всё, кроме оконной функции, в подзапросе либо CTE.

Comment: Спасибо. Надо подумать наш Вашими словами )))

Comment: Пока что самостоятельно не могу понять как это сделать. Можете написать код? Скорее всего нужно подсмотреть как эту задачу решают более опытные люди.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Стоит указывать, какая задача решается.

Если "для каждого юзера найти OS, c которой он заходил в последний раз", то

```
SELECT
        global_user_id
        , os_family_1
    FROM (
        SELECT
            MD5(COALESCE(bums.global_user_id::VARCHAR, 'NULL')) AS global_user_id
            , dos.os_family_1 AS os_family_1
            , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY bums.global_user_id ORDER BY fpv.page_view_date DESC) AS rn
        FROM "database"."data_warehouse__prod"."fact_page_views" AS fpv
        LEFT JOIN "database"."data_warehouse__prod"."dim_browser" AS dib ON dib.browser_key = fpv.browser_key
        LEFT JOIN "database"."data_warehouse__prod"."dim_os" AS dos ON dos.os_key = fpv.os_key
        LEFT JOIN "database"."data_warehouse__prod"."dim_page" AS dip ON dip.page_key = fpv.page_key
        LEFT JOIN "database"."data_warehouse__prod"."dim_snowplow_user" AS dsu ON dsu.snowplow_user_key = fpv.snowplow_user_key
        LEFT JOIN "database"."data_warehouse__prod"."outrigger_dim_site" AS ods ON ods.site_name = dip.page_app_id
        LEFT JOIN "database"."data_warehouse__prod"."bridge_user_model_snowplow" AS bums ON dsu.snowplow_user_key = bums.snowplow_user_key
        WHERE
            fpv.page_view_date::DATE >= (('2022-02-02'::DATE + -8 * INTERVAL '1 week'))
            AND fpv.page_view_date::DATE < (('2022-02-02'::DATE + 0 * INTERVAL '1 day'))
            AND (dib.is_a_bot) = 'This Is Not A Bot'
            AND (dib.is_internal_traffic) = 'This Is Not Internal Traffic'
            AND (ods.site_id IS NOT NULL)
        ) AS os_family_1
    WHERE rn = 1
```

Comment: Да, для каждого юзера найти OS, с которой он заходил в последний раз. Но строку, которая у меня идет как "MD5(CONCAT(CASE WHEN bums.global_user_id::VARCHAR IS NULL THEN 'NULL'::VARCHAR ELSE bums.global_user_id::VARCHAR END)) AS global_user_id" менять не могу - она должна быть как есть у меня в оригинале (там своя мутка в общем).

Comment: я не менял, просто упростил выражение

Comment: ну и на результат поиска она не влияет

Comment: да, Вы правы. большое спасибо!